# Is there a way to open more then one program at a time in python.

Tags: python

I want to write a python program that with one click I can open several different files, gmail and I.E. to a particular web address at work.  I know the following will open calculator but once it opens chrome nothing else will open until chrome is closed.  Any suggestions.

```
import os
os.system('calc.exe')
os.system('chrome.exe')
os.system('file path')
os.system('Another file path')
```

Comment: You should use the `subprocess` module. You can create any number of subprocesses and Python doesn't wait for one to finish before starting the next (unless you ask it to).

Comment: u can use Multi threading if you want to open multiple program at same time.In case you didnt know about it.

Comment: subprocess.Popen('program name') worked.  Thanks